# How to interpret referrers from Google News in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

Not specifically a programming question, unfortunately, but I am trying to develop some custom reports using the Google Analytics Core Reporting API (v3) and I'm stuck on how to interpret these referrers (in ga:referralPath or document.referrer) from Google News sites:

- /nwshp
- /news/rtc
- /news/url
- /
- /news/story
- /news/i

... and so on. These are all coming from Google News sites (.com .whatever) obviously, but I'd like to categorize them with more granularity if possible, e.g., Google News front page, etc.

Many thanks in advance (and feel free to point me to a better place to ask, if such a place exists).

Answer (score 0):

[According to Chris Boutet](https://twitter.com/chrisboutet/status/314092743339147264), these represent Google News Home page (/nwshp) and Google News Realtime Coverage (/rtc). That's the answer I was looking for. Hope that helps.